# CodeBuild failing to pull file from S3 in docker build

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I have a CodeBuild Project which runs a docker build command with a buildspec.yml like this

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the Docker image...          
      - docker build -t $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG .
      - docker tag $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG      
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo Pushing the Docker image...
      - docker push $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG
```

However during the docker build process I have a sh script that runs the aws s3 cp command. I have given the service role permissions to the bucket and the error I get is.

```
+ aws s3 cp s3://bucket/file /var/www/html/filelocal
fatal error: Unable to locate credentials
```

Do roles not propagate through to Docker on Codebuild?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are building an isolated file system. If you ran the docker build locally with the credentials on your local machine, you would see the same behavior. You would have to add credentials to your container to run those same operations. With that said, you could add credentials to your container via build-args *or* you could just use the codebuild role to gather the files you need and then copy those into the container during the build process. I would vote for the second way so you don't have to worry about cleaning up the credentials before publishing the container. Although you can query the environment to get the role's temporary credentials, which means you probably wouldn't have to worry about cleaning those up, you could just as easily remove those concerns by just letting the codebuild role handle gathering the files you need to build the container.

Comment: If you want credential's you do have to pass them in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-versions. Overall I was not a fan of the solutions here so I changed it to pull from S3 in the entrypoint to avoid having to deal with clean-up or passing it down.